# OrientDB slow write

Tags: java, orientdb

OrientDB official site says:

> On common hardware stores up to 150.000 documents per second, 10
>   billions of documents per day. Big Graphs are loaded in few
>   milliseconds without executing costly JOIN such as the Relational
>   DBMSs.

But, executing the following code shows that it's taking ~17000ms to insert 150000 simple documents.

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument;

public final class OrientDBTrial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/foo");
        try {
            db.open("admin", "admin");

            long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 1; i < 150000; ++i) {
                final ODocument foo = new ODocument("Foo");
                foo.field("code", i);
                foo.save();
            }
            long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(b - a + "ms");

            for (ODocument doc : db.browseClass("Foo")) {
                doc.delete();
            }
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }

}
```

My hardware:

- Dell Optiplex 780
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93Ghz
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 7 64bits

What am I doing wrong?

Splitting the saves in 10 concurrent threads to minimize Java's overhead made it run in ~13000ms. Still far slower than what OrientDB front page says.

Comment: Were you able to get the most performance? I study this problem, but my performance is even worse than you

Comment: I've decided to use H2 instead of OrientDB. H2 fits my use case.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by using 'Flat Database' and orientdb as an embedded library in java 
see more explained here
http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/JavaAPI

what you use is server mode and it sends many requests to orientdb server, 
judging by your benchmark you got ~10 000 inserts per seconds which is not bad, 
e.g I think 10 000 requests/s is very good performance for any webserver
(and orientdb server actually is a webserver and you can query it through http, but I think java is using binary mode)

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation first on how to achive the best performance!

Few tips:

**->** Do NOT instantiate ODocument always:

```
  final ODocument doc;
  for (...) {
    doc.reset();
    doc.setClassName("Class");
    // Put data to fields
    doc.save();
  }
```

**->** Do NOT rely on `System.currentTimeMillis()` - use `perf4j` or similar tool to measure times,  because the first one measures global system times hence includes execution time of all  other programs running on your system!

Comment: There is no problem for such a long running test to use System.currentTimeMillis as a stopwatch. Of course you could do some warmup before measuring (and use nanoTime), but I dont think that changes the result by an order of magnitut. You can even hand-measure the time and it would be valid.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers from the OrientDB site are benchmarked for a local database (with no network overhead), so if you use a remote protocol, expect some delays.

As Krisztian pointed out, reuse objects if possible.