# Parameters affecting the speed of insert records to the OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I add records to OrientDB and my count of inserts per seconds equals 40-50. My code is copy/pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205471/orientdb-slow-write). My database is remote and consist of two nodes.

Is there some specific configurations, that affect to write speed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked and applied suggestions from: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Performance-Tuning ?

Comment: Yes, I tried change parameters of VM, but there isn't changes with perfomance.

Comment: I mean all the other suggestions about Massive Insertion, did you follow them?